# Android/Java : Is there a way to call the return of the method after a listener triggered?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, monitor, notify

I'm using Volley to get a JSONObject from an HTTP Api.

My problem is that I want my method to wait for the *Response Listener* getting the result, otherwise my method is returning a null object. 

I tried using synchronize wait and notify to achieve it, but it doesn't seem to work, the activity freezes after the *isFinished.wait()* and the listener doesn't trigger. Can you tell me what's wrong in my code ?

```
public JSONObject query(String url) throws InterruptedException {
    finished=false;
    Req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            synchronized (isFinished){
                Retour = response;
                finished = true;
                isFinished.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            synchronized (isFinished){
                Retour = null;
                finished = true;
                isFinished.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });
    Queue.add(Req);
    synchronized (isFinished) {
        while (!finished) {
            isFinished.wait();
        }
        return Retour;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'wait for the Response Listener' means blocking the main thread, your ui will be stuck for the duration and system will show that your app is not responding..

Comment: I recommend changing the design  by having a custom listener object that will fire when either onResponse() or  onErrorResponse() is triggered. What you want is a suspended function, something available in Kotlin but not easily doable in Java.  So I recommend a different design approach.

Comment: You might also look into ```CountdownLatch``` and see how that can be used for signaling as well.

Comment: @Jarvis Thank you for your advice, I solved my issue by passing a callback function (using Consumer<Void>) as an argument to the method. It is then called by the Response listener, without interrupting my main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the design, so the method doesn't return anything, but calls back a *Consumer interface* that then retrieve the Result into a class field *Data* :

```
Consumer<JSONObject> cons = a -> Data=a;
```

The original code became :

```
public void query(String url,Consumer<JSONObject> cons) {
    Req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Retour = response;
            callb.accept(Retour);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Retour = null;
            callb.accept(null);
        }
    });
    Queue.add(Req);
}
```